# Are the following convergent or divergent?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Are the following convergent or divergent? Justify

$1.\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$

$2. \left(\frac{1}{ln(n)}\right)^\infty _{n=2}$

$3.\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n/4}\cos(\pi n/100)$

My thoughts are:

$1.$ is covergent because for $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{\ln(n)}$, $  \lvert\frac{1}{\ln(n)}\rvert$ is decreasing as $n\to\infty$, so by the Alternating series test, $\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ converges.

$2.$ is divergent because $n>\ln(n) \implies \frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{\ln(n)}. $

Because $ \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^\infty _{n=2}$ diverges and $\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$. So, by the comparison test, $ \left(\frac{1}{\ln(n)}\right)^\infty _{n=2}$ diverges.

Is what I've written so far true?

My most trouble comes from 
$3.$

I think it converges to $0$, but I'm not sure under what tests it does.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am unsure, but doesn't $\left(\frac{1}{\ln(n)}\right)^\infty _{n=2}$ mean to look at a sequence from $n=2$ to $\infty$, not the actual sum of the terms?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I think you're totally right. Silly me haha.

Comment: No problem, silly notation mix ups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first - don't only state that $|\frac{1}{\ln(n)}|$ is decreasing - the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{1}{\ln(n)}|=0$ is certainly relevant.

The alternating series test states:

> if $|a_n|$ decreases monotonically, all $a_n$ are positive or all negative, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$, then the alternating series $a_0-a_1+a_2-\cdots$ converges.

It is not enough to say $|a_n|$ is decreasing, nor is it to say that $|a_n|$ is monotonically decreasing and bounded. Take for example $a_n=1+\frac{1}{n}$, which is monotonically decreasing, and certainly bounded. But the alternating series $a_0-a_1+a_2-a_3+\cdots$ definitely doesn't converge - since each $a_n$ is about 1 for large $n$, this series keeps bouncing back and forth (this is obviously not a formal proof that it doesn't converge; I hope I made my point clear though).

---

For the second, probably the sequence is meant rather than the series; $(a_n)_{2}^{\infty}$ is common notation for the sequence $(a_2,a_3,a_4,...)$, and as such, the question is, does the sequence $(\frac{1}{\ln(2)},\frac{1}{\ln(3)},\frac{1}{\ln(4)},...)$ converge? As you noted, $\ln(n)$ goes to infinity as $n$ approaches infinity - thus, $\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ approaches $0$ as $n$ approaches infinity, and therefore the sequence converges.

---

You only need the comparison test for the third one - simply note that $|\cos(\pi n/100)|\leq 1$. Can you now bound $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n/4}\cos(\pi n/100)$ by something you do know converges?

As you might know, $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$. We can use this fact on the above series to note

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n/4}\cos(\pi n/100)\right|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|2^{-n/4}\cos(\pi n/100)\right|$$

and we know that $|2^{-n/4}\cos(\pi n/100)|=|2^{-n/4}||\cos(\pi n/100)|\leq 2^{-n/4}$ and thus,

$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n/4}\cos(\pi n/100)\right|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n/4}$$

Now the only thing left for you to do is find a bound or value to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n/4}$.

Comment: Well you need the comparison test for the 3rd don't you :)

Comment: Yes you do, but I never considered that as a test since it's so intuitive. I'll edit my answer though :)

Comment: Oh you're totally right about he 2nd one. I was confused. Would that be by the absolute convergence test or is it by another test? Thanks :D

Comment: Could I say that because it is monotone decreasing and is bounded, then it is convergent?

Comment: @vrugtehagel Would the series that I compare it to be the geometric series 1/2^n?

Comment: @eulersnumber I updated my answer, I hope I made myself a little clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The first looks good.

The second looks good if you meant to take $\sum^\infty _{n=2}\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$, but as written, its just a sequence:

$\left(\frac{1}{\ln(n)}\right)^\infty _{n=2}\to0$

The third may be handled with absolute convergence, noting that

$$|\cos(x)|\le1$$

Thus, we are left with

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty2^{-n/4}$$

Which is a geometric series and converges.